# proptypes error when using material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, material-ui

i just started a reactJS project and when i decided to use material-ui it statrted throwing a lot of errors like this one:

> bundle.js:12441 Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. Read more at fb.me/use-check-prop-types Check the render method of `CardHeader`.

my App component looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import NavBar from './common/NavBar';
import Logo from './common/Logo';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuithemeProvider';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Logo />
          <NavBar />
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

App.PropTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

> material-ui version: 0.20.0
>
> react version: 15.0.2

Comment: @ThomasFauskanger it’s a material ui’s component. And it throws this error on every component i’m using. React’s and mine (including that App component)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
App.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```