# Proptype error in material ui / reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-proptypes

i just started a reactJS project and when i decided to use material-ui it statrted throwing a lot of errors like this one:

bundle.js:12441 Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the prop-types package. Use PropTypes.checkPropTypes() to call them. Read more at fb.me/use-check-prop-types Check the render method of CardHeader.

React version: 15.0.2
Material ui version: 0.20.0

Comment: Are you using React.Proptypes anywhere yourself

Comment: At first i used react.proptypes and then i changed it to the ‘prop-types’ library. But it still shows these warnings

Comment: In that case it maybe coming from a  dependency that hasn't yet updated it in its implementation. Make sure to update all the other libraries to the latest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proptypes error when using material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956980/proptypes-error-when-using-material-ui)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks! Working now

Comment: Are you importing the prop-types library like thing: import PropTypes from 'prop-types';?